# Why does "string.matchall is not a function" error pop up even though I pass a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, selenium

I am using `string.matchAll()` to match patterns in a string. In doing so, I get a type error `string.matchAll is not a function`.

Consider the string input "i am a string".

I use the code below to find patterns in the string. Although the string doesn't contain the pattern I am looking for, it still works well. However, sometimes I get a type error.

```
match_pattern = (string_to_parse) => {
    const pattern = /\[\d+@(?<name>[^\]\r\n]*)]/g;
    const matches = string_to_parse.matchAll(pattern);
    let prev_match_pos = 0;
    const string_parts = [];
    for (const match of matches) {
        string_parts.push(string.substring(prev_match_pos, match.index));
        string_parts.push(<strong>{match.groups.name}</strong>);
        prev_match_pos = match.index + match[0].length;
    }
    string_parts.push(string_to_parse.substring(prev_match_pos, 
    string.length));
    return string_parts;
};
```

For this string with patterns works well
  "i am a [1@string hello]"

But the string "i am a string" has the type error problem. Could someone let me know what's the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: which browser you're working with ?

Comment: Does it work at all? `string_parts.push(<strong>{match.groups.name}</strong>);`?

Comment: Not supported on IE, Edge, or Safari apparently.

Comment: yes it works perfect and i am using chrome browser

Comment: when i perform this string operation manually i dont see the error. but when i use selenium robot tests then i see this error.

Comment: very true adiga... i tried replacing matchall with .exec and it worked with selenium.

Comment: Does your error message say `matchall` or `matchAll`?

Comment: it says matchAll. i fixed this by updating chromedriver. and it recognises string.matchAll method now.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

1- You were missing quotation marks on this line (**edit:** or maybe a string literal?):

```
string_parts.push(`<strong>${match.groups.name}</strong>`);
```

2- I assume you meant `string_to_parse.length` instead of `string.length` on this line:

```
string_parts.push(string_to_parse.substring(prev_match_pos, string_to_parse.length));
```

So the code becomes:

```
match_pattern = (string_to_parse) => {
    const pattern = /\[\d+@(?<name>[^\]\r\n]*)]/g;
    const matches = string_to_parse.matchAll(pattern);
    let prev_match_pos = 0;
    const string_parts = [];
    for (const match of matches) {
        string_parts.push(string.substring(prev_match_pos, match.index));
        string_parts.push(`<strong>${match.groups.name}</strong>`);
        prev_match_pos = match.index + match[0].length;
    }
    string_parts.push(string_to_parse.substring(prev_match_pos, 
    string_to_parse.length));
    return string_parts;
};
```

And this now seems to work fine on my browser.